# Tomcat returns 404 status

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets, tomcat6

I was trying to change the user who runs the tomcat process.

In process of changing I have added new user and made tomcat run under him.

how now if i ping the tomcat, I get 404 error.

I am not sure how to proceed.

Can I check if tomcat has loaded all the classes ?
Can I check anything else to make sure tomcat loaded the servlets.

Is there anything else I can check to resolve this 404 error.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Look in Tomcat's logs and post any error you may find. Also, verify the ownership and/or filesystem permissions of the files under `webapps` to make sure they are readable by the Tomcat user.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what operating system you are using. Look in your tomcat logs directory and verify that tomcat actually started up. A lot of times the log will be called catalina.out. It should say "server starting up in X ms". Also, look at the running processes on your system. There should be a Java process running for Tomcat. You can also use netstat or dig on Linux to see if there is a process listening on a particular port. You can check what port Tomcat should be listening on by looking in the conf directory and looking at the Tomcat server configuration in the server.xml file.